# Can't make_unique a base class

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

The code here is complaining that the line with push_back is trying to create an object of type Abstract.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory> 

class Abstract
{
public:
    Abstract() {}
    virtual void   f()  = 0;
};

class Derived : public Abstract
{
public:
    Derived()  {}
    void f()  override  {   }
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Abstract>> vec;

    vec.push_back (std::make_unique<Abstract>(new Derived)); 

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error messages:

```
error C2259: 'Abstract': cannot instantiate abstract class
```

I thought `unique_ptr` would just take the pointer w/o thinking about what it pointed to?

Answer (score 5):

`make_unique<T>` creates an object of type `T`. *Always*. It basically does `return unique_ptr<T>(new T(args...));`.

If you're using `new` to create the pointer yourself, you don't want to pass that pointer to `make_unique`. Not unless you're doing `make_unique<T*>` or something that takes a pointer to an object.

You can `push_back(std::unique_ptr<Abstract>(new Derived()))`, or you can `emplace_back(new Derived())` if you prefer.

Comment: So what do I do instead? Before `unique_ptr`, I had a vector of Abstract*.

Comment: @TopologicalSort `std::make_unique<Derived>()` is what you want

Comment: Guillaume, that didn't have any effect on the error, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the object in place by using `emplace_back`:

```
vec.emplace_back (new Derived);
```